# Makefile loop through sourcefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am currently trying to setup my first Makefile in Windows for simple c++ projects to be able to use it for every single project i create with only a few changes needing to be done.
Here i get my sourcefiles from all folders:

`sources := $(wildcard src/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/*/*.cpp) $(wildcard include/*.cpp) $(wildcard include/*/*.cpp)`

which gives me following output:
`src/main.cpp src/core/console.cpp src/core/filehandler.cpp src/core/framework.cpp src/core/globals.cpp src/core/textureeditor.cpp src/ui/buttonfuncs.cpp src/ui/interface.cpp src/ui/userinterfaces.cpp`

Now i want to compile my files into object files like so:

```
$(OBJDIR)%.o: $(sources)
    @echo compiling $< to $@
    @$(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)
```

It outputs:

```
compiling src/main.cpp to obj/main.o
compiling src/main.cpp to obj/console.o
compiling src/main.cpp to obj/filehandler.o
compiling src/main.cpp to obj/framework.o
compiling src/main.cpp to obj/globals.o
compiling src/main.cpp to obj/textureeditor.o
compiling src/main.cpp to obj/buttonfuncs.o
compiling src/main.cpp to obj/interface.o
compiling src/main.cpp to obj/userinterfaces.o
```

which makes clear that it takes the right object files but doesnt take the right file from sources.

Is there a solution to iterate through sources or maybe delete the first element of sources every time this is run? Or maybe a better solution to this?

Side note: .o files always match up with .cpp files in the list as the .o names are being generated from the sources list.

I tried to get foldernames into srcs_dir:

srcs_dir = $(foreach wrd,$(sources),$(dir $(wrd)))

and running it like so:

```
$(OBJDIR)%.o: $(srcs_dir)%.cpp
    @echo compiling $< to $@
    @$(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)
```

with following output:
`make: *** No rule to make target` obj/main.o', needed by `debug'.  Stop.`

Entire Makefile:

```
#defining project settings
project_name := Nimble
version := 0.0.1

#defining compiler settings
INCLUDE_PATHS := $(foreach wrd,$(wildcard src/*/),-I $(dir $(wrd))) \
    $(foreach wrd,$(wildcard include/*/),-I $(dir $(wrd)))
LIBS := -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -llua54
CC := g++
CPP := c++20
DEBUGFLAGS_O := -std=$(CPP) -Wno-missing-braces -w -g -Wall -m64 $(INCLUDE_PATHS)
RELEASEFLAGS_O := -std=$(CPP) -Wno-missing-braces -w -O3 -Wall -m64 $(INCLUDE_PATHS)

#defining paths
OUTPATH_DEBUG := bin/debug/$(project_name)
OUTPATH_RELEASE := bin/release/$(project_name)
OBJDIR := obj/
SRCDIR := src/

#getting headers
headers := $(wildcard src/*.h) $(wildcard src/*/*.h) $(wildcard include/*.h) $(wildcard include/*/*.h)
#getting sourcefiles
sources := $(wildcard src/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/*/*.cpp) $(wildcard include/*.cpp) $(wildcard include/*/*.cpp)
srcs_dir = $(foreach wrd,$(sources),$(dir $(wrd)))
#object_files := $(sources:.cpp=.o)
srcs = $(foreach wrd,$(sources),$(notdir $(wrd)))
object_files := $(foreach wrd,$(srcs:.cpp=.o),$(OBJDIR)$(wrd))


print:
    @echo Object Files:
    @echo $(object_files)
    @echo Sources:
    @echo $(sources)
    @echo srcs:
    @echo $(srcs)
    @echo include paths:
    @echo $(INCLUDE_PATHS)
    @echo headers:
    @echo $(headers)
    @echo srcs_dir:
    @echo $(srcs_dir)

debug: FLAGS := $(DEBUGFLAGS_O)

release: FLAGS := $(RELEASEFLAGS_O)

release: $(object_files)
    @$(CC) obj/*.o -o $(OUTPATH_RELEASE) -s -L lib/ $(LIBS)
    @xcopy graphics\\ bin\\release\\graphics\\ /s /Y

debug: $(object_files)
    @$(CC) obj/*.o -o $(OUTPATH_DEBUG) -L lib/ $(LIBS)
    @xcopy graphics\\ bin\\debug\\graphics\\ /s /Y

$(OBJDIR)%.o: $(sources)
    @$(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)

clean:
    @echo > Cleaning Object files
    @cd obj/ && del *.o
    @echo > Cleaning
```

Comment: Are you looking for `$(OBJDIR)%.o: src/%.cpp`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am looking for all "src/SUBDIRS/%.cpp", "src/%.cpp", "include/SUBDIRS/%.cpp" and "include/%.cpp"

Comment: Please show your complete makefile as it exists currently.  You may be better off using `vpath` directives in this particular case.

Comment: @G.M. I edited my question and included the entire Makefile i currently have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As G.M. suggests you want to [use `VPATH` or `vpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html).  In a pattern rule the stem (the part that matches the `%`) must match the identical string in the target and the prerequisite.  There is no way to say "this, plus random other subdirectories".

To use VPATH you would do something like this:

```
sources := $(wildcard src/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/*/*.cpp) $(wildcard include/*.cpp) $(wildcard include/*/*.cpp)
object_files := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(sources)))

VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(sources)))

  ...

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)
```

Most make functions, like `$(dir ...)` and `$(notdir ...)`, accept a list of words to operate on so you don't need to use a loop and pass them one at a time.

Also, please don't add `@` prefixes to your recipes until they fully work, else you're just throwing away important debug information.

Comment: thank you, it worked for me! I tried "vpath" before and it didnt work at all even if i used your syntax ... the reason was simply because i did it lowercase ... uppercase it works just fine.

Comment: The `vpath` lowercase uses a different syntax.  The description of how to do it is in the manual section I linked above.  It will work as well, but `vpath` (lowercase) is NOT a variable so you should not assign it as a variable.  See specifically https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html